# Retrieving data from SQLite in Unity3D

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm Having a problem with my query

HighScoreGrammarI

-- getting data from sqlite

```
 private void GetGrammarIScore()
    {
        highScores.Clear();

        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(Connection))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string select = String.Format("Select Hs_date, Hs_answer, Hs_score from Highscores_data where Hs_stage = 'GrammarI' and Hs_name = (\"{0}\")", Username.text);

                dbCmd.CommandText = select;

                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        highScores.Add(new HighScore(reader.GetDateTime(0), reader.GetInt32(1), reader.GetInt32(2)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

-- showing data using the get data void

```
 private void showGrammarI()
    {
        GetGrammarIScore();
        for (int i = 0; i < highScores.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject tmpobjec = Instantiate(ScorePrefab);

            HighScore tmpScore = highScores[i];

            tmpobjec.GetComponent<HighscoreScript>().SetScore(tmpScore.Date.ToString(), tmpScore.CorrectAnswer.ToString(), tmpScore.Score.ToString());
        }
    }
```

HighscoreScript

```
public GameObject Date;
    public GameObject CorrectAnswer;
    public GameObject Score;

    public void SetScore(string date, string correctanswer, string score)
    {
        this.Date.GetComponent<Text>().text = date;
        this.CorrectAnswer.GetComponent<Text>().text = correctanswer;
        this.Score.GetComponent<Text>().text = score;
    }
```

HighScore

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }

    public HighScore(DateTime date, int correctanswer, int score)
    {
        this.Date = date;
        this.CorrectAnswer = correctanswer;
        this.Score = score;
    }
```

THE ERROR IS HERE:

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.VerifyType (Int32 i, DbType typ)
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.GetDateTime (Int32 i)HighScoreGrammarI.GetGrammarIScore () (at Assets/Script/HighScoreGrammarI.cs:73)  >> this line is inside the while query in HighscoreGrammarI

Comment: Have you tried individually running the the cast for each column, to see which ones fail and which ones succeed?

Comment: not yet...thanks i will  try :)

Comment: Has your first field from Highscore_data the correct format?